# Add multple lists together and have label for each nested list

Tags: python

I have a bunch of list objects. I want to be able to combine them all and give label to them.

What I have is:

```
list_a = [[32, 0.0], [51, 1.4]]
list_b = [["APPLE", 0.7], ["BANANA", 0.0]]
list_c = [[32, "CAT"], [41, "DOG"]]
```

**What I want:**

```
[
  ["list_a", [32, 0.0], [51, 1.4]],
  ["list_b", ["APPLE", 0.7], ["BANANA", 0.0]],
  ["list_c", [32, "CAT"], [41, "DOG"]]
]
```

Unfortunately, **what I get currently:**

```
[
  ["list_a", [[32, 0.0], [51, 1.4]]],
  ["list_b", [["APPLE", 0.7], ["BANANA", 0.0]]],
  ["list_c", [[32, "CAT"], [41, "DOG"]]]
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
def my_method (some_param: str) -> list:
    list_a = some_method().values.tolist()
    list_b = some_method().values.tolist()
    list_c = some_method().values.tolist()

    final_list = [["list_a", list_a]] + [["list_b", list_b]] + [["list_c", list_c]]
    return final_list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to unpack the second list

`[["list_a", *list_a]] + [["list_b", *list_b]] + [["list_c", *list_c]]`

additional information about this operator https://geekflare.com/python-unpacking-operators/